# How can I search values by key pattern in redis

Tags: redis, node-redis

I made a user keys on REDIS like that.

The pattern > u:info:(userNumber):userId
example >
          mset u:info:1:userId Jack, u:info:2:userId Mason, u:info:3:userId Justin

And I wanna have userId list. 
I have a solution for that. First, use SCAN and parsing all keys and make an array using parsed userNumber like that arr = [1,2,3]. Second, execute a command like below.

command > mget u:info: + arr[0] + :userid, u:info: + arr[1] + :userid ...

But It needs the parsing stuff. I wanna do it just using a command. Is there any good way for that?

Comment: You can use HSET and store different properties of each user in different hash fields

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I'll upvote if you write a real answer

Comment: @ItamarHaber same here!

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Thank you! I am so happy to get the answer. Well.. but I was thinking about using HSET at first. But I thought It will spend more memory. (If the structure change ziplist to hash table, it will make robj for each key and values. That size will be bigger than sdshdr).. That's why I chose SET.

 Do you usually use HSET when you implement user tables? I'm doing like below
> MSET u:info:3:userId Jack, u:info:3:age 27, u:info:3:gender M

Comment: @JackPark if the objects are small and you set the ziplist limits correctly, it's the way to go.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Okay. I will try! Appreciate for your time.

Comment: @ItamarHaber Thank you for your comment, If you have better idea, Please let me know.

Comment: @JackPark better than @Not_a_Golfer's? Surely not.